# Python read string of very very large number from file and convert it to int for use

Tags: python, file, encryption, rsa, readfile

I have to read a cipher file that has paragraphs of digits that I need to decrypt using RSA's decryption formula: `m = (c ^ d) % n`.

This is my decrypt function:

```
def Decrypt(file, n, d):
    with open(file, 'r') as fifi:
        for line in fifi.readlines():
            x = int(line)                 # reads message file byte by byte
            with open("dec.txt", 'a') as wr:    
                wr.write(chr(pow(x,d,n))) # write to file as string
                wr.close()
```

Python compiler would compline to me about the pow funtion:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C int
```

What should I do? thx in advance

Comment: `pow` isn't limited by C int, e.g. this works `pow(10**100,11**99,12**50)` so make a [mcve] and provide a full stack trace.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I imagine it's the call to `chr` where that is limited to a max val of `0x10FFFF`. OP, why are you using that function?

Comment: @MarkTolonen to convert my encrypted integer to its original form, that is, character. I decrypt a number using pow then get the ascii character.

Comment: @flakes I imagine the OP should learn to make a [mcve] and provide a stack trace 

Comment: So you're saying that the "original form" of your data was a *single character*?  That's the only thing `chr()` can produce.  You probably want `str()`, instead.

Comment: never mind it turns out something was wrong with my vscode so i just restarted it and now it works fine! here's my source code if anyone is curious https://github.com/layan00/RSA thanks everyone